# Excel: find value in column, then search for date value in that row, return value to the left

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for a formula (or code) that finds a value in a column, then find the value in that row between dates, when multiple dates return the max, then returning the value to the left. I cannot use a helper column. I tried a couple of nested index/match formula's but without success...

For the below example:

Parameter 1: Find **Fork** in Column A

Parameter 2: In that row (4), find date between: 1 Jan 18 AND 5 Jan 18

Parameter 3: when multiple dates are found in that date range, return the max

Parameter 4: Return the value from column left of that date

Result: **black** in Column D.

```
    A       B       C           D       E           F             G
1   ID      Colour 1Date 1      Colour 2Date 2      Colour 3      Date 3
2   Plate   Green   1-Jan-18    Red     23-Jan-18   L blue        14-Feb-18
3   Bowl    Blue    6-Jan-18    Brown   28-Jan-18   Yellow/Green  19-Feb-18
4   Fork    Yellow  2-Jan-18    Black   4-Jan-18    Turquoise     24-Feb-18
5   Knive   Purple  16-Jan-18   White   7-Feb-18    Maroon        1-Mar-18
6   Spoon   Pink    21-Jan-18   Orange  12-Feb-18   L pink        6-Mar-18
```

I hope it is possible! Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

where
`I10` = ID to search for
`I11` = Min Date (1 Jan 2018)
`I12` = Max Date (5 jan 2018)

`J10` = `=MATCH($I$10,$A$1:$A$6,0)` get the row number if the ID

```
=INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,),
       MATCH(
             MAXIFS(INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,),
                    INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,),">="&$I$11,
                    INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,),"<="&$I$12
                   ),
             INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,),0
             ) - 1
      )
```

were
`INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,)`get the data row for the ID (repeated several time in formula)
`MAXIFS(...)` get the maximum date meeting the `>=` and `<=` criteria
`MATCH(MAXIF(...), [ID data row],0)` get the column number for the date returned by the `MAXIF`
`INDEX( [ID data row], MATCH(MAXIF(...), [ID data row],0) - 1)`returns the color

---

Alternative Formula without `MAXIFS`

```
=INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,),
            MATCH(
                  MAX(IFERROR(({0,0,1,0,1,0,1})*(INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,)>=$I$11)*(INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,)<=$I$12)*(INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,)),0)),
            INDEX($A$1:$G$6,$J$10,),0
            ) - 1
      )
```

Enter as an Array Formula (complete with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks so much!! However, I am using Excel 2013 and not 2016 so MAXIFS is unfortunately not a functionality I have (yet). As my Excel is server driven I cannot upgrade it at the moment.

Comment: @Inge You "accept" or say thanks by upvoting and clicking the arrow symbol - found top left of the answer...